# How to deep copy a observable array into normal jquery array

Tags: jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have a observable array nested under another observable array, this array is binded to UI.

On button click I am copying main observable array to a jquery array and doing some manipulation however when i change new jquery array my old observable array items are getting changed.

Below is the snippet.

1. Observable Array

   ```
   var masterArray = ko.observableArray([{"name" : "Tom",
               "lastName" : "Jerry",
               "license" : ko.observableArray([1,2,3])},
               {"name" : "Jack",
               "lastName" : "Sparrow",
               "license" : ko.observableArray([4,5,6])}]);
   ```
2. Deep Copy to normal Jquery Array

   ```
   var clonedArr = $.extend(true, [], masterArray());
   ```
3. Changing Value in new array which affect old array.

   ```
      clonedArr[0].license(7);
      console.log("after deep copy: "+ masterArray()[0].license())
   ```

Am i doing anything wrong? see the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hdrrd7gj/

Comment: i think you have to manually look into your source observable array to see if its child content is a primitive data or an object and need to decide the cloning logic. `$.extend()` really don't know the knockout framework. So you will have to write your own logic for such deep cloning.

Comment: You really should edit your old question instead of posting  a one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38109341/deepcopying-observable-array-knockout

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's deep extend will correctly deal with primitives, objects and arrays. Your `license` property however, is neither of those. It's a function:

```js
var license = ko.observableArray([1, 2, 3]);
console.log("Type of license: " + typeof license);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

This means jQuery won't be able to understand how to clone it, even though it's quite simple:

```js
var cloneObsArray = function(obsArray) {
  var innerArrayClone = obsArray().slice();
  return ko.observableArray(innerArrayClone);
};

var originalArray = [1,2,3];
var originalObsArray = ko.observableArray(originalArray);
var clonedObsArray = cloneObsArray(originalObsArray);

// Test if the clone is actually a clone
originalObsArray.push(4);
clonedObsArray.pop();

console.log("Data source: ", originalArray);
console.log("Original: ", originalObsArray());
console.log("Cloned: ", clonedObsArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Concluding: if you want to clone an object that contains observable properties, you'll need a custom clone method. In plain javascript:

```
var innerCloneMethod = function(obj) { /* todo */ };
var masterArray = ko.observableArray([ /* .... */ };
var clonedArray = masterArray()
  .map(innerCloneMethod)          // Returns a new array with cloned inner objects
```

One way of quickly cloning knockout viewmodels is to use the `ko.mapping` plugin. This plugin has the methods `toJS` to create a plain object, and `fromJS` to translate a plain object into a new viewmodel.

```js
var innerCloneMethod = function(obj) {
  return ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.mapping.toJS(obj))
};

var original = {
  a: ko.observable(1),
  b: 2
};

var clone = innerCloneMethod(original);

original.a(2);
console.log("Original a: " + original.a());
console.log("Clone a: " + clone.a());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
```

The drawback here is that you need a custom options object to prevent `name` and `lastName` from being translated into observables.

Personally, I'd create a `UserViewModel` with `name`, `lastName` and `licenses` properties, and a `clone` method that returns a `new UserViewModel` with similar values.